# Kinda CRM Solution with Google App Engine (?)

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

Dear programmers and developers,

I am doing a research on an application development. I don’t know much about Google App Engine and I come from Microsoft applications development environment.

Our organization have a specific need to keep track of directory information, such as (profile picture, name, phone number, gender, email address, etc). We would also like to send survey questions to the individual and keep the history (so that the individual does not have to answer the same question over and over).

My questions is if that would be possible in Google Apps Engine. If not, is there a better fit? However, it has to be a hosted solution as we do not have the infrastructure to house web application. Following are a few high level requirements:

(There are about ~1,000 people in our organization and ~100 groups. There is a group leader assigned to each group.)

---

- The group leaders will login and input the directory information for
  their team initially.
- The group leaders only see the list of their team.
- The group leaders may sometime reassign the members to another group.
- There will be checks in place so that team members do not belong to
  multiple groups by mistake.
- The group leaders will fill out weekly reports. The application will
  save the reports for historical archive.
- The application will send a reminder to the group leaders when they
  miss the weekly report.
- The application will send scheduled emails to ~1,000 people to update
  their directory information twice a year.
- The application will email reminders to those who have not yet
  updated the information.
- Tight integration with emails - the application will email survey
  questions to ~1,000 people periodically and save the replied-email
  responses associating with the directory information.
- Email reminders to those who have not responded to the questions.
- There will be some automated executive summary reports emails out to
  the executive leaders.
- Tight integration with Google Apps Edu edition and Google Docs (if
  possible).

---

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Linn

Comment: Your list is possible but what is your question? There is quite a bit of work so a boilerplate might help you get started

Comment: Thank you for answer my question very quickly, @peterretief. my question was a general one to see whether GAE would be a good fit for what we need. We are trying to decide which platform to go with. Apparently they are many options, Drupal, Azure, Amazon, etc.

Comment: I guess what you are familiar with would be a good start, some advantages of the google offering would be integration with other google products like mail and contacts. I dont have experience with Heraku or Azure but I am sure they have their fans